# php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate doesn't work

Tags: php, api, symfony, migration

in my symfony project, after adding the topo property to my  Media entity related OneToMany to Topo entity  I did the migrations,

```
php bin / console make: migration
```

It works .But with

```
 php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

I have the errors described on the two images.
[image: error with php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate]
[image: same error with php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate]

In addition to that,  the topo view route, topo_show, the following bug:

```
App \ Entity \ Topo object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation.
```

My entity file media is :

```html
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use App\Repository\MediaRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation\Uploadable;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;



/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MediaRepository::class)
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Site::class, inversedBy="media")
     */
    private $site;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;
    
    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="sites", fileNameProperty="image" )
     * 
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $maj;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Topo::class, inversedBy="media")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $topo;

    public function __toString(){
        return $this->nom;
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getSite(): ?Site
    {
        return $this->site;
    }

    public function setSite(?Site $site): self
    {
        $this->site = $site;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNom(): ?string
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    public function setNom(?string $nom): self
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getImage(): ?string
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    public function setImage(?string $image): self
    {
        $this->image = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of imageFile
     */ 
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of imageFile
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setImageFile($imageFile)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get the value of maj
     */ 
    public function getMaj()
    {
        return $this->maj;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of maj
     *
     * @return  self
     */ 
    public function setMaj($maj)
    {
        $this->maj = $maj;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getTopo(): ?Topo
    {
        return $this->topo;
    }

    public function setTopo(?Topo $topo): self
    {
        $this->topo = $topo;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I can't find the solution yet.
And more, I have my API which crashed, which can no longer find the hydramember.
Could you help me? Thank you

Comment: Can you share your entity files as well?

Comment: In fact It was the topo property to my  Media entity related OneToMany to Topo entity

Comment: Thank you, I found out a solution

Comment: @DiegodeMassy if you found the solution please add your answer below your question.

Comment: In the folder migrations, file Version20210005200553.php,  the requests to apply the migrations (ADD CONSTRAINT FK, CREATE INDEX) are in the up () function of your Version20210005200553 class. The requests to undo the migration and revert to the previous version (DROP FOREIGN KEY, DROP INDEX) are in the down () function. The idea is to Try to go back to the previous version of the database by executing the down () function requests to remove the indexes, constraints and columns to finally try to apply the migration again.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)